# Azure Function App setting from Key Vault accessible with system assigned identity but not with user assigned one

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to set up my Azure Function App with some settings loaded from Key Vault. I was able to successfully do that by configuring IAM on the key vault by assigning role  `Key Vault Secrets User` to system-assigned managed identity associated with the Function App.

Now I am trying to do the same thing but with user-assigned managed identity. I have:

1. created new Managed Identity
2. associated the identity with the Function App
3. configured IAM on key vault to assign role `Key Vault Secrets User` to the identity

All this is done within one Resource Group.

Now when I re-deploy the function, it shows following error on the settings page:

> AccessToKeyVaultDenied
>
> Key Vault reference was not able to be resolved because site was denied access to Key Vault reference's vault.

I am clearly missing something, but I can't figure out what. Can somebody help me?

Cheers,
Maciej

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the Function App the id of the user assigned identity to use to resolve Key Vault references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#access-vaults-with-a-user-assigned-identity.

The `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` property on the Function App needs to be set to the resource ID of the user assigned identity.

Sample Bicep template here: https://yourazurecoach.com/2022/02/04/use-app-service-key-vault-references-with-user-assigned-identities/